# Should I change every controller method to be async if one of them is changed?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, async-await

There is this controller file, SecretAuthController.cs

```
    public class SecretAuthController : Controller 
    {
          public ActionResult Auth()
          {
               //library method whose signature recently changed to async

              return ProcessTelemetry();
          }        
    }
```

So, my colleague changed this code to

```
        public class SecretAuthController : MyBaseController
        {
              public Async Task<ActionResult> Auth()
              {
                   //library method whose signature recently changed to async                  
                   await MyLib.GetTaskDetails(Id);
                   return ProcessTelemetry();
              }        
        }
```

In this process,  they also changed all other controller methods signature too to use 1`async`.

So, some methods look like

```
     public Async Task<ActionResult> ExFooTest()
     {
           //There is no awaitable call here
           //normally returns.
     }
```

Few doubts regarding this:

1. If there is no awaitable call, is it wise to change the method signature to use `async` ?
2. Is it a general rule, that if we want to change one action method signature to use `async`, should we need to change all the action method signature ? (Assume they don't **await**)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> If there is no awaitable call, is it wise to change the method
>   signature to use async ?

No, you shouldn't. I think Visual Studio even gives you a hint about it:

> This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously

`async` was introduced to make it easier to handle I/O, DB and other high latency operations. That doesn't mean that it should be used all the time. It still produces some overhead, and it is more likely to give you a negative performance impact if used when not needed. Only use `async` when you actually `await` something. And when you do you should do it *all the way*.

Now we talk about `Controllers`, which often is the entry point of an application.  But let's look at situation from a wider perspective. What if you have a repository that is used by a couple of other classes which for some reasons cannot use `await`. If that repository made all it's methods `async` it would simply cause all the other classes to lock the thread while awaiting the operation.

Instead you should think about what you have to *gain* from using `async`. Can the consumer `await` it and will it improve performance? If it's `async` all the way, then yes. Otherwise, probably no.

Further reading:

[Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

[Why shouldn't all functions be async by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498942/why-shouldnt-all-functions-be-async-by-default)

[Should I worry about "This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously" warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29923215/should-i-worry-about-this-async-method-lacks-await-operators-and-will-run-syn)

Answer (score 1):

You only need to make function async if there is an awaitable/async functionality in it. There is no need or a requirement to change all actions to async.