# Why not make all functions async JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I understand async/await are really just promises but I'm curious if there's a reason not to make all functions async and await all value for consistency?

## My Question

Is there any issues or implications to making all functions async? Are there any drawbacks?

This is for both Node.js and Client side systems (transpiled)

Comment: Though asked for a different language, this question has some pointers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498942/why-shouldnt-all-functions-be-async-by-default

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46900782/what-is-the-overhead-of-javascript-async-functions

Answer (score 0):

For many functions, you just want a result, and you want it now. Why would you go through all the extra overhead and complexity of async?

In other words, yes there are implications: there is almost certainly going to be a performance hit; partly because the code will be more complex.

Comment: since promises are part of the language and not a "on top" library or something similar, the runtime can decide to execute a promise immediately. there is not a performance hit in client computing rather than allowing your application to deliver steady 60 fps