# What is the effect when enabling the Async page tag .NET framework 4.8 web forms?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, webforms, .net-4.8, asp.net-4.8

I am working on a project that is using the .NET framework 4.8 tech stack (I know that it is old) with a web forms project. The project is running fine, but I have a question with consideration to make.

I was memory testing an example .NET framework 4.8 Web forms application, where I was using all async pages and async methods. It was using a smaller amount of memory using the async variants during startup, but also after. I think that this [Async page attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/ydy4x04a(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) is better and should be used.

However, if it is always better to use the async flag, then why did they put a feature flag behind the functionality? Because you need to manually set the Async=true attribute on all pages like the example below:

```html
<%@ Page Title="YourTitle" Async="True" %>

<asp:Content runat="server">

</asp:Content>
```

So the question is, I can understand the advantages, but what are the disadvantages? If there were only advantages, they would not put a feature flag behind it (I think) and they would just patch it as a optimization.

Can you help me to find the disadvantages? I cannot find anything that explains that online.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why shouldn't all functions be async by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18498942/why-shouldnt-all-functions-be-async-by-default)

Comment: No, I want to know the impact when all pages are async, but the code behind the pages are not yet. The "Why shouldn't all functions be async by default?' does not answer that. So, to be clear again: I want to know the impact of async page handling, not why i should not make everything async